# How to combine IF statements in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to put this line in my batch program:

```
IF eventValue GTR 800 IF eventValue LEQ 805 SET eventEffect=tax
```

Either I have the syntax wrong or something else is wrong. My question is, if I want the `event value` to be between `800` and `805` for the `eventEffect` to be set to `tax`, is this the right syntax? or is there a different way to set two `IF` perimeters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error do you get?  The syntax looks right to me.

Comment: I'm not getting any real "errors" per se, but the program immediately does `echo  %eventEffect%` and  `echo  %eventValue%` afterwords, and even when it fits within the parameters, `eventEffect` just says its default string "nothing"

Comment: You're missing the `%`s around your variable names. `if %eventvalue% gtr 800 if %eventvalue% leq 805 set eventEffect=tax`.

Comment: Can you post your entire code?  Also, how did you verify that `eventValue` really was within the range?  Could you add an `echo` statement to be certain?

Comment: @SomethingDark You're right!! dumb mistake. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

A different way to get the same result:

```
set /A "test=0, aux=(800-eventValue)*(eventValue-805), test=(aux-1)/aux" 2>NUL
if %test% equ 0 echo The value is in 800-805 range
```

Explanation:

```
set /A (lowLimit-value)                            is negative or zero if value >= lowLimit
set /A (value-UpLimit)                             is negative or zero if value <= upLimit
set /A (lowLimit-val)*(val-UpLimit)                is positive or zero if value is in range,
                                                   negative otherwise, and
set /A aux=(Low-val)*(val-Up), test=(aux-1)/aux    set test=0 if value is in range,
                                                   test=1 otherwise
```

This is a very efficient method to test if a *numeric* value is inside a given range, that may even be extended to test for *several ranges* [in the same expression](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3493); a small special management is required as a precaution against possible division by zero in case the value be exactly one of the limits.

Answer (score 1):

Well, other than making them variables as @somethingDark mentioned, here are a few other options;

```
:: On one line with parentheses:
if %eventValue% gtr 800 (if %eventValue% leq 805 (set eventEffect=%tax%))

:: Code blocks across multiple lines;
if %eventValue% gtr 800 (
    if %eventValue% leq 805 (
        set eventEffect=%tax%
    )
)

:: An odd, but occasionally useful in difficult code blocks check method;
set "isTax=true"
if not %eventValue% gtr 800 set "isTax=false"
if not %eventValue% leq 805 set "isTax=false"
if %isTax% equ true set eventEffect=%tax%
```